# Stop propagation when clicking on a Autocomplete MUI component in an accordion

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to add an `Autocomplete` component in an `AccordionSummary` but when I click on it, the accordion expands and has a `focus` state.

I tried stopping the propagation but it doesn't work.

How can I stop the propagation so the accordion doesn't expand and doesn't have a focus state ?

Here is a reproductible example : https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-cdn-k46ut6?file=/src/App.tsx:333-349

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### UPDATE (10-16-23)

The `focus` event of the `Input` component was bubbling up, causing it to fire for the `AccordionSummary` component. Stopping propagation at the `Input` did the trick. See updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-carson-2zmrcx?file=/src/App.tsx).

#### ORIGINAL

To stop propagation on the mui `Autocomplete` component you'll need to override the `onClick` event in both the rendered Input and the Listbox Component.

```js
<Autocomplete
  ListboxProps={{ onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation() }}
  renderInput={(props) => 
    <TextField 
      {...props} 
      InputProps={{ 
        ...props.InputProps 
        onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation(),
        onFocus: (e) => e.stopPropagation(), // Added with update
      }} 
    />
  }
/>
```

For more information on the Autocomplete API, see the [Autocomplete documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/).

Comment: Unfortunately, these changes continue to trigger the `focus` state on the accordion when clicking on the `AutoComplete` component :/ Could you give me a reproductible example using codesandbox please ? Here's what I tried : https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-hermann-d6y2fx?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @GabrielDeMoura Updated my answer. The focus event was bubbling up from the Input as well.